# Intercepting a form submition into a pop-up window with jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload, popup

I'm using a pop-up window to upload images to imageshack provider using their api.

My goal is, in the main window, to get the returned xml from the form upload inside the pop-up window (in order to get the thumb and image links of the uploaded image) and insert this data into some hidden fields in the main window.

**edit**
My iter is:

1. The user click a button on my site (example.com)
2. I open a pop-up with a form inside (example.com/form.html) via `window.open`
3. The form's action goes to Imageshack api url
4. The user upload the image, the form is submitted, imageshack api return some xml.

I need to get that xml in the main window, parse it to get the original image and thumbnail url, then close the pop-up.

This becose i dont like my user to have to copy'n'paste the html from imageshack into a field on my site... its just for convenience.

So, how can I detect when the form gets submitted, and how do I get the returned xml?

p.s: im using imageshack to low tmy servers bandwith and cpu usage for images, so i **cant** upload the image on my server and then store on imageshack (via server-side languages)

Comment: by popup window do you mean a modalDialog, new window or some sort of floating div?

Comment: I mean a pop-up window via `window.open()`.
A floating div (iframe?) would be better, but the form action is on another domain, so i dont think i can accass to the output generated in a iframe.
With a pop-up, i 'just' need to get its dom *after* the form has been submitted, so i'll get the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many try, with all possible tricks&hacks, what i was looking for is not possible, due to browser's security policy.

Answer (score 0):

When you make your ajax request with Jquery, in the callback function is where you should initiate the popup. When the response comes back, store the xml somewhere on the page. Possibly a hidden textarea with an Id.

Once the xml has been stored on the page, you can then access the value with the following line of javascript running inside the popup:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
```

Comment: ok no problem, when the xml comes back from your request. Spit it out on the main window as well as some javascript to initiate the popup. Access the value in the same way as I mentioned in the original answer.

Comment: I cann put javascript in the 'first stap' of the pop-up, but not on the results page where the form get submitted.. i tryed to access the pop-up from the main window, but i get `Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'`.. i guess it is a browser's security rule... and looks like i cant even get back with `window.opener[...]` solution, after the form has been submitted.